# Dismissing Keyguard Screen in Android

Tags: android

I have an issue where Keyguard Screen is coming infront of incall screen.Need a way dismiss the Keyguard Screen.This is on 4.1 android version.I tried all the flags of windowmanager.layoutparams but did not succeed in dismissing the keyguard screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
keyguard = km.newKeyguardLock("MyApp");
```

to disable keygurd

```
public void unlockPhone() {
    keyguard.disableKeyguard();
}
```

and dont forget to re enable it

```
public void lockPhone() {
    keyguard.reenableKeyguard();
}
```

dont forget to use DISABLE_KEYGUARD permissionin.

Comment: class KeyguardLock is deprecated since API 13.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html
On device like Amazon Kindle Fire HD, it causes app to stop

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on KitKat
In onCreate before setContentView and after super

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)   getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    lock.disableKeyguard();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you tried both FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html

Have you included the DISABLE_KEYGUARD permissionin the manifest?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DISABLE_KEYGUARD

If all else fails, maybe this will help:
http://www.xplorationstudio.com/xploreandroid/?p=23

Answer (score 0):

The activity must have a fullscreen window in order to work, besides the above answers.