# Is there any way to do something like `requestDismissKeyGuard` under api level 25?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-windowmanager, keyguard

I want to request dismiss keyguard to user. But `KeyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard()` can only use over api level 26.
If device is locked with pin code security, `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` isn't working like `requestDismissKeyguard()`.

```kotlin
when {
                // Android 8.0以上
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1 -> {
                    setShowWhenLocked(true)
                    setTurnScreenOn(true)
                    val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
                    keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
                }
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
                    window.addFlags(
                        FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    )
                    val keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
                    keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null)
                }
                else -> {
                    window.addFlags(
                        FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    )
                }
            }
```

If there is another way, I would like to know.

Thank you.

Comment: `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` can be used below API 26, but I see you're already using that.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I assume that device is locked with security pin code.
So `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` couldn't solve this case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried under API level 25, but I found these answers,

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
keyguard = km.newKeyguardLock("MyApp");
```

Disable and re-enable it:

```
public void unlockPhone() {
    keyguard.disableKeyguard();
}

public void lockPhone() {
    keyguard.reenableKeyguard();
}
```

As I got the answer from:
[Dismissing Keyguard Screen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360503/dismissing-keyguard-screen-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I think this way can use only no device security lock setting. @sophin